# How to print contents of data (on a Div, table, form etc) automatically without a print-dialog window- (WebClientPrint-Neodynamic)

Tags: php, neodynamic

I'm following through the PDF version on this URL: https://www.neodynamic.com/articles/Print-PDF-from-PHP-directly-to-default-printer-without-print-dialog/

I have managed to have it running. However, I noticed that it can only print one PDF file that is saved, using the   $filePath = 'files/LoremIpsum.pdf'; under the PrintPDFController.php file. Is there a way of dynamically getting contents from a database that is output on say a table as follows:

```
        <table id="WebClientPrint">
        <tr><td>ONLY PRINT THIS PART AUTOMATICALLY</td></tr>
        </table>

        <input type="button"  onclick="How to call Table ID i.e. WebClientPrint and the default printer" value="Print" />
```

This means that at button click, only the contents of the table should be printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I once used this type of printing and it helped me, only the window for choosing a printer will pop up.

```js
        function PrintDiv() {
            var contents = document.getElementById("dvContents").innerHTML;
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                window.frames["frame1"].print();
                document.body.removeChild(frame1);
            }, 500);
            return false;
        }
```

Use it like this

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">Sample code</span>
    <hr />
    <div id="dvContents" style="border: 1px dotted black; padding: 5px; width: 300px">
        <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial">Hello,
            <br />
            This is <span style="color: #18B5F0">Mateo</span>.<br />
            Hoping that you are enjoying my articles!</span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" onclick="PrintDiv();" value="Print" />
    </form>
</body>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The printer dialog is what the real problem is. I need a bypass for that and that is why am using the WebClientPrint by Neodynamic library for this. Try using it also to understand what I require

Comment: OK I get you but you will need to  chose the printer for you to print and that the the only dialog this code pops up.

Comment: I you have not tested it you can so that you see what it does.